# Why Bootstrap in Yii framework works slower on windows mobile?

Tags: javascript, performance, yii, windows-mobile

I have built a web application that contains barcode reading with windows mobile .
When using the mobile , it takes about 4 seconds to put the read barcode in the text box while it's so fast in the web.

I tried to find what is causing the problem , so I removed the bootstrap register and it works efficiently on the mobile , but i must use bootstrap because it has the style of my site and everything needed to make it compatible with the web application !

I tried to figure out what causes the slow in the bootstrap and after commenting the javascript register lines in `Bootstrap.php`

```
 protected function registerJS( $position = CClientScript::POS_HEAD )
     {
         /** @var CClientScript $cs */
         $cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
       //  $cs->registerCoreScript('jquery');
       //$filename = YII_DEBUG ? 'bootstrap.js' : 'bootstrap.min.js'; 
      //$cs->registerScriptFile($this->getAssetsUrl() . '/js/' . $filename,
 $position);
     }
```

it gets better , but as I said before ,I can't get rid of bootstrap , I searched the web and tried to read the js file but I don't know if it's possible to find what's making it slower hrough this ?
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

When you scan barcode data into a web input field, the data is transmitted by somewhat wedge via the keyboard message queue to the foreground application (the web browser). The application itself then routes the message to the element with input focus.

Now, if the input field or the app does some verification or other stuff on any key press, this will slowdown the input performance.

I have seen apps that redraw the whole screen on every key press. That is a real performance killer.

Look inside the framework you use and watch for the route the key press input takes to get into the input field.

Comment: I couldn't find an answer for this problem because the code works correctly on browser . I commented all the javascript files as you see in question above and kept the CSS .
jquery still works , it's from the yii .

Comment: Try to find help at the yii community: http://www.yiiframework.com/community/. Sorry